# jQuery to change value on submit

Tags: jquery, forms, paypal

I have a problem by using a PayPal donation-button.

The currency format for PayPal is defined with a dot. In europe our currency uses comma. This causes a problem where after submitting the form PayPal says that there is a wrong format for the amount.

Usually it would not be an issue to simply use `str_replace(',','.', $_POST['amount'])` but the form will be send directly to PayPal so that there is no chance to validate/replace the input by using php.

That is why I need to use jQuery.

The basic idea is to check if there is a comma in the value and in case just replace the comma with a dot and return true to post the form.

```
$(function() {
    $('#paypal').submit(function() {
           if ($('#amount') contains a comma) {
              replace comma with dot;
           }
      }
        return true; 
    });
});
```

I usually don't use jQuery. So if there is some who could help me out I really would appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with [`regex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) if there will be multiple `,` in the `amount`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#paypal').submit(function() {
        $('#amount').val($('#amount').val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
        return true;
    });
});
```

`g` flag will make sure that all occurrences of `,` are replaced.

---

If there will be only one `,` you can use `replace` without `regex`(*faster*)

```
$('#amount').val($('#amount').val().replace(',', '.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` all the occurrences of comma to dot.

```
if ($('#amount').val().indexOf(',')!=-1) {
      $('#amount').val()=$('#amount').val().replace(/,/g,'.')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String `replace()` Method.

```
var str = '190,89';
var res = str.replace(",", ".");
```